# Laravel How to access another model's function in model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to use a function inside from different model. 
For example: I have a 3 model. Two of them are connected with belongsTo. Another one is absolutly different model.

However i need to use that function in different model. 
Is there a way to

```
public function foo()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\B', 'App\C', 'id', 'category_id');
}
```

do something like that?

I also tried this:

```
public function investmentCategory($id)
    {
        app('App\Investment')->category($id);
    }
```

In my view:

```
$news->investmentCategory($news->id)->slug
```

used like that. But i got this error.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::investmentCategory()

Any solution for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not have a relationship with this table, it is better to bring this method to the controller or another class; you do not need to do this in the model of this table.

Comment: can you explain what models you have and their relationships?

Comment: I can't made it this way and change the method. But my question is still exist. "A" Controller has queries with all models. Also "B" model has belongsto "C" model. I need to display "B" models values and "B" categories. That categories stays in "C". Its kinda complicated i think.

Comment: can you elaborate more in your question?